# I need help naming villagers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft, and I'm customizing a village I found. I'm trying to give nametags to all the villagers, but when I try, all I get is the trading menu. I've heard of the Nether portal method, but I'm afraid of the villager accidentally walking into the portal. Any other methods?

Comment: Have you tried shift-clicking?

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing multiplayer let your friend right click on the villager when he is in the trading menu right click the villager with the name tag.

Answer (score 0):

Rename a villager spawn egg, then kill a villager and spawn a new villager on it's place.
 If you are doing it in survival, try sneaking while renaming.

Comment: Sneaking while renaming does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This works on all versions (1.0 - 1.10.2). Don't be scared of teleporting into the nether; just do it quickly.

1. Create a nether portal.
2. Place the villager front of you.
3. Go to the Nether.
4. Switch item to name tag.
5. Return to the Overworld.
6. Stand inside Nether portal without moving.
7. Apply the name tag on the villager.
8. Quickly push the villager to prevent it from going to the nether.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade. Your answer look good, but with caps at the beginning of sentence, it would be a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning that the need to use a nether portal or other crazy methods has been fixed in 16w33a, and you can just right click while holding the name tag.

If you're ok with updating to snapshots, can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy, you don’t need a portal at all. I was gonna use a portal and was dragging the villager over to the portal with a boat, but then I noticed if you hover over the villager with a name tag in your hand, you can actually name the villager! I tried this on my iPad in Minecraft PE and it works every time!